# Почему вызов ServerSocket.accept() ловит один клиентский запрос несколько раз?

Tags: java, http, сокет

Я писал свой <strike>крутой</strike> сервер.
Вот `Main` класс:

```
Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final HTTPServer server = new HTTPServer(9999);
        server.start();

        System.out.println("Server started!");

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            server.stop();
            System.out.println("Server stopped!");
        }));
    }
}
```

А вот мой класс `HTTPServer:

```
HTTPServer {

    // для дебага
    private static int threadNumber;
    private final int port;
    private Thread listenThread;

    public HTTPServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    void stop() {
        listenThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

А теперь самое интересное - метод `HTTPServer.start()`:

```
void start() {
    listenThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

                while (!interrupted()) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    threadNumber++;

                    System.out.println(threadNumber+"==========================");
                    socket.getOutputStream().write(("\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\"Connection: close\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
//                  socket.getOutputStream().write("abrakadabra".getBytes());

                    socket.close();

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    listenThread.start();
}
```

И вот этот вот "милый" код, после одного запроса на *http://localhost:9999/*, выдает:

> Server started!
>   1==========================
>   2==========================

**Но это не так страшно!**
Если закомментировать строку `socket.getOutputStream().write(("\"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\r\\n\"Connection: close\r\n\r\n").getBytes());` и раскомментировать `socket.getOutputStream().write("abrakadabra".getBytes());`, то программа выдает:

> > Server started!
> >     1==========================
> >     2==========================
> >     3==========================

Что думаете об этом?

Comment: Что значит "после одного запроса"? Вы с браузера заходите?

Comment: "Zergatul" - да, с Chrome

Comment: @JolpNem, для ответа пишите @ и ник

Answer (score 0):

Это браузер запрашивает `favicon.ico`, что бы отобразить иконку сайта. Вы можете прочитать запросы от браузера, и проверить.

Comment: Забыл сказать, что об этом я уже подумал и отключил favicon.ico; но даже в таком случае почему он ловит три раза?